# Hide command window on batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm running a batch file that starts a telnet session to an Extreme network switch, disables several ports, then closes the window. Can someone show me how to adjust my code so that both windows are completely hidden from view? Right now I'm using the last 3 lines for the VBS script to ALT+F4 the window. This works 9 of 10 times, but sometimes fails to close the window.

Thank you!

Batch File

```
?Batch File (named disable.bat ):
 :: Open a Telnet window
start telnet.exe 10.3.100.26
 :: Run the script 
cscript disable_script.vbs
```

VB Script

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Login to Switch
OBJECT.SendKeys "admin{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "password{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50 
  'Logout
OBJECT.SendKeys " enable ports 1-5{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 25 
OBJECT.SendKeys "quit{enter}"
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "n{enter}"
WScript.sleep 50 
  'Close Telnet Window
OBJECT.AppActivate "Telnet"
WScript.sleep 200
OBJECT.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [telnet that's actually scriptable](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttytel.exe)?

Answer (score -1):

I found [this Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file) which worked fine with a batchfile for me. It just pop's up for half a second and disappears then. Also, it worked out all the time whenever i used it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.